# How to set tool path relative to current project in PhpStorm's Command Line Tool Support

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm's Command Line Tool Support for using Laravel's `artisan` as a "Tool based on Symfony console" as shown below:

[image]

Problem is I want to share this across all my projects (global scope). But if I hard code the path to `/home/user/project/artisan` in Tool path then it runs the that project's directory (not my currently open one). If I just put `artisan` it doesn't run.

Is there a template variable like `$ProjectDir$` or something I can add in the Tool path?

Comment: Make it per project entry -- much better and less possible headache. P.S. Can `artisan` (just command like that) be used in global scope in actual terminal (in any random folder)? No as you have to run it in the right folder or specify full path to the `artisan` file. Follow the same logic here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just do that. It's not that hard to create a new tool in every project. P.S. Is there is an xml file I can copy-paste? I use it to copy my run/debug configs (you told me in another question), so just checking if the same approach can work for command line tools too. thanks!

Comment: It will be stored in separate .xml file inside `.idea/commandlinetools` subfolder. You should be able to just copy-paste it between different projects (while target project is closed in IDE, of course) with minimal edits (like path to the tool for example).